# Appending an object to a predefined array

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble adding a new object to an array.

I have this function, `addValue(shopItem, subTotal)`, where `shopItem` is a string and `subTotal` is an integer:

```
function addValue(shopItem, subTotal)
{
    document.getElementById("extraSubHeader").innerHTML = "Current Total: " + subTotal + " Gold";

    var object = {name: shopItem.name, description: shopItem.description}
    alert("Bought " + shopItem.name + " for " + subTotal + " Gold.")
    playerItems.push(object);
}
```

`playerItems` is an array of objects, by default it contains this:

```
playerItems = [
    { name: "Sword", description: "An old, rusty sword." }
];
```

However, when I try to add the new variable `object` (above), it instead wipes what I've already entered into the array and replaces it with whatever is in `object`.

---

EDIT: I've added a console.log(); to show the `playerItems` object, and it does in fact contain both objects. It must be a problem with how I iterate and display it. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: A simple test in the console of this code works fine?

Comment: the code snippets you've posted are ok - something in the code you haven't shown is the problem

Comment: Looks fine. How do you know that playerItems is being cleared? Do you have other places where you refer to playerItem and might accidently assign a value instead of `push`?

Notice that you're passing in `subTotal` which you are using both as a subtotal in the first line, and as the price of the single item in the `alert`

Comment: @javinor Elsewhere, I loop through playerItems, and if you click the button to do this at the beginning of the program it shows the predefined sword object, however if you then go to the shop and buy the potion, clicking the button only shows the potion.

Comment: I see two potential problems in your code: 1you have var object - which is bad practice to call variables object, even though in reserverd words list for javascript there is "Object" and not "object" I would still avoid using that word in my code. 2.You said the shopItem is a string, but if you accessing shopItem.name and shopItem.description it means shopItem is not just a string it is an object. I am not sure if this two things is causing your code perform differently or not, but it is definitely worth checking.